# Java - Does not change int in if-else

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My value (int or float) doesn't change in if-else. When I take value, it says default.

```
float iwantchangethis = 0;

  if (vararaba == true | varkamyon == true) {
    canvas.drawLine(besyuzatmis, yediyuzyirmi, yan, ust, paint);
    if (trackedPos.centerX() > 360) {
      float iwantchangethis = (yan - 360) / 4;      //doesn't change
    } else if (trackedPos.centerX() < 360){
      float iwantchangethis = (360 - yan) / 4;      //doesn't change
    } else {
      float iwantchangethis = 0;
    }
```

Comment: `|` is a bitwise operator. You'll want to use the logical operator `||` instead. Also, no need for `== true` when comparing booleans. `if (vararaba || varkamyon)`

Comment: Thanks for tips, I will try them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because visibility of the variable is `{}` and you create every time separate variable with same name.

```
float iwantchangethis = 0;

  if (vararaba == true | varkamyon == true) {
    canvas.drawLine(besyuzatmis, yediyuzyirmi, yan, ust, paint);
    if (trackedPos.centerX() > 360) {
      /*float*/ iwantchangethis = (yan - 360) / 4;      //doesn't change
    } else if (trackedPos.centerX() < 360){
      /*float*/ iwantchangethis = (360 - yan) / 4;      //doesn't change
    } else {
      /*float*/ iwantchangethis = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake where I printed the value. And I can't take new value. Thank you so much. Have a good day :)